# I ejected my React app and configured it to use css modules for styling, but I keep on getting this error on npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, css-modules, react-scripts

I ejected my React app and configured it to use css modules for styling, but I keep on getting this error when I run `npm start`:

```
/home/beckhamochieng/Desktop/React/react-complete-guide/config/webpack.config.dev.js:227
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    ^

TypeError: webpack.NamedModulesPlugin is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/beckhamochieng/Desktop/React/react-complete-guide/config/webpack.config.dev.js:227:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
```

Comment: A React App created through CRA, by default, supports "CSS Modules", so no need to do `npm eject` for enabling CSS Modules.

Comment: Thank you Ajeet, I also upgraded my react-scripts version.